# Get specific posts by ID in wordpress

Tags: posts, get-posts

I am new to word press, And I am working on posts, I have total 10 posts in my admin panel, I tried to get the posts by their ID's but it outputs the latest five posts.

here is my code sample. I don't know where I am going wrong here, A little hint would be highly appreciated.

```
<?php
            $thePostIdArray = array("11", "13", "15", "17", "19");
            $limit = 5;
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $counter++; 
            if ( $counter < $limit + 1 ) : $post_id = $thePostIdArray[$counter-1]; $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
        ?>
        <a href="/applications">
        <div class="col-md-5 apps text-center">

            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' )); ?>

            <div class="caption">
                <h3><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default home-page-explore hvr-grow-shadow">
                    Explore
                </button>

            </div>
        </div> </a>

        <?php endif; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

See, I have specified the ID's in the array, but It doesn't show these ID's and shows the latest 5 posts from the amdin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
        $thePostIdArray = array("11", "13", "15", "17", "19");
        $limit = 5;
        $query=new WP_Query(array('post__in'=>$thePostIdArray));
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); $counter++; 
        if ( $counter < $limit + 1 ) : $post_id = $thePostIdArray[$counter-1]; $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
    ?>
    <a href="/applications">
    <div class="col-md-5 apps text-center">

        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' )); ?>

        <div class="caption">
            <h3><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h3>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default home-page-explore hvr-grow-shadow">
                Explore
            </button>

        </div>
    </div> </a>

    <?php endif; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: it gives syntax error on $query. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')' in

Comment: Syntax error...try now....